# How to simulate mouse click or movement in remote server when remote connection is down?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have simulated mouse click and mouse movement. it working great when you are connected to remote server. it is using my mouse to click or move.
when i minimize or close remote connection, it wont do any thing. it want it to continue when i close my remote connection.
Is there any way to do so?

This is how i simulate click:

```
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x,y, 0, 0);
```

More info:
My app is running in my remote server. i do connect to remote server. start my app. the app will open cefsharp browser and click on some elements. i want to close remote while my app (reside in server) continue clicking. there is no client and server. it is just an app reside in my vps.

**Answer:**

when you are disconnecting  from remote server, it will be logged out and you need to log in to execute app. Using this batch script, you can disconnect without signing out :

```
tscon %sessionname% /dest:console
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provide use local Windows API which work on local machine not remote system. you should separate your architecture to client and server and deploy and agent on remote computer which listen on requests and make mouse movement there.

Comment: My app is running in my remote server. i do connect to remote server. start my app. the app will open cefsharp browser and click on some elements. i want to close remote while my app (reside in server) continue clicking. there is no client and server. it is just an app reside in my vps